# how do i use <a href> tag in a servlet to access an html file?

Tags: html, servlets, href

I have a html file addemployee.html which i need to call from a servlet.

I have tried following statements .. but neither are working:

```
out.print("<a href='/addemployee.html'>1.Add New Employee</a>");
```

`out.print("<a href=/"addemployee.html/">1.Add New Employee</"a>");`

Always getting error 404.The html file is stored in the same package as the servlet.

Can anyone please tell what the problem could be.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried pasting the url into a browser to make sure it is correct and available?

Comment: when i am trying to access the html file through servlet url is http://localhost:8084/WebApplication1/addemployee.html but when i open it directly in a browser its file:///C:/Users/dhruv/Documents/NetBeansProjects/WebApplication1/src/java/project/addemployee.html

Answer (score 3):

You are missing context root. You can use any of the following:

```
out.print("<a href='addemployee.html'>1.Add New Employee</a>");  // relative if on same level as servlet
out.print("<a href='/WebApplication1/addemployee.html'>1.Add New Employee</a>");  // absolute - hardcoded context
out.print("<a href='" + getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/addemployee.html'>1.Add New Employee</a>");  // absolute - context read from configuration
```